# <pageCount/> not rendering in OpenERP 7

Tags: python, odoo, rml

I am working with OpenERP 7

I want to modify my invoice report footer to show the current page and the total number of pages like this :

> page:1/2 in the first page and
>
> page:2/2 in the second page...

this is my code:

```
<place x="1.3cm" y="0cm" height="1.55cm" width="19.0cm">
                <para style="main_footer">[[ company.rml_footer ]]</para>
                <para style="main_footer">Page: <pageNumber/>/<pageCount/></para>
</place>
```

but pageCount don't return any number. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello everybody and thank you all for your answers.

In fact, after a deep and hard search I discovered that `<pageCount />` tag will not return any value when we put it in a `<place />` tag so I put it in a `<drawstring />` tag and it returns the total number of pages. Here is my code:

```
 <place x="1.3cm" y="0cm" height="1.9cm" width="19.0cm">
           <para style="main_footer">
                 Page: <pageNumber/>/
           </para>
 </place>
 <drawString x="11.36cm" y="1.64cm" ><pageCount/></drawString>
```

I know that this solution is not professional, but it did work, hope that this bug will be fixed soon.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

It is a bug that not fixed yet. Take a look here [pageCount Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+bug/516966). Maybe problem can be solved by a small patch attached there.

Comment: @Ethan Furman, I am not able to add comments due to less reputation. I tried your solution, I've applied the patch you've specified but still I am not getting the correct output. **<pageCount/>** is till not working.

Comment: I see towards the top there was an initial, and much bigger, patch.  Maybe that one will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you write, in your footer:

The total number of page will be written at the exact place chosen (here x="10.5cm" y="0.8cm", x and y start from the left-down corner). Beware that if you type:
Total Pages: 
then the  tag will overlap with the label 'Total Pages:' (this is because the  is filled as a final step). So make sure to have this  tag alone in the  tag at the coordinates you'll have chosen.