# Page x of y in rml report

Tags: report, odoo, rml

In Openerp v7 rml reports,  does not render in  section. For example this displays nothing:

```
<para style="foo"><pageCount/></para>
```

It does though render if used in between , but it is not a good option, because exact x:y position needs to be specified, and styling cannot be applied also.

Any other ways to achieve "page x of y"? A workaround exists, maybe?

Comment: Did you mean <para style="foo"><pageCount/></para>

Comment: Yes, i misstyped it. It doesn't work either way.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20433006/2194671), It is not so professional, but it works.